# Load information only one time in ViewController

Tags: iphone, web-services, download, load

Im programming an application that use WebServices. When i pass from my View7Controller to my View8Controller i load a lot of information of my WebServices, and it is a long time.

I want load this information only the firts time that launch the application. I need do it between View7Controller and View8Controller, because i need send information to my WebService that only i can load here.

Someone can help me please?

Thanks friends!

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

How about a boolean that is false first and true after you loaded the data once?

Comment: isn't all programming actually? :) but did this help? Were you able to solve your problem?